# Can not find screen and how to install it without network and administration?

Tags: gnu-screen, ncurses

I am working on an HPC with LSF job system.

`screen` works fine on logon node and most of the computation nodes which I can ssh into them. `which` command shows that `screen` is located under `/usr/bin`.  But I found on some node, bash just can not find screen, and mysteriously, I can not find `screen` under `/usr/bin` on that node. But I have to use it.

So I think maybe I can install a local version of `screen`, so I download the `screen-4.5.1.tar.gz` package. However, `./configure` terminated with error

> configure: checking for tgetent... configure: checking libcurses...
>   configure: checking libtermcap... configure: checking libtermlib...
>   configure: checking libncursesw... configure: checking libtinfow...
>   configure: checking libncurses... configure: checking libtinfo...
>   configure: error: !!! no tgetent - no screen

Google shows that we need to either `sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev` or `sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev`. However, I am not administrator and I have no internet connection on HPC. So I think manually install `ncurses` should be fine. I downloaded `ncurses-6.0.tar.gz`. configure, make, make install, finally I got 4 folder in my custom folder `myInstall_ncurses`: bin, lib, include, shared.

But How should I install `screen` now? I tried this

```
./configure --bindir="/home/myInstall_ncurses/bin" --includedir="/home/myInstall_ncurses/include" --libdir="/home/myInstall_ncurses/lib"
```

But the error is the same. What is wrong?

Comment: Those configure options determine where `screen` gets installed. Try `./configure --help` and there should be an option that lets you specify where `ncurses` is

Comment: Hi, @Fox, thank you but If I know which is the option, then I won't need to post this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `ncurses` installed in `/home/myInstall_ncurses`, and there are `lib` and `include` subdirectories of that:

```
export LDFLAGS='-L/home/myInstall_ncurses/lib'
export CPPFLAGS='-I/home/myInstall_ncurses/include'
./configure --prefix='/where/to/install/screen'
make
make install
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! But one more question, I found specifying LDFLAGS only will successfully make. It seems that `include` is not needed. Is there potential different between adding `CPPFLAGS` and not adding `CPPFLAGS`?

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` here was to specify the include directory, in case that was needed. It may or may not be, depending on what headers were included

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Is using `LIBS=-L/home/myInstall_ncurses/lib` equivalent to `LDFLAGS=-L/home/myInstall_ncurses/lib`? any difference?

Comment: They might act the same, but in general they aren't. `LDFLAGS` is for specifying where things are, while `LIBS` is more for specifying extra things to link, I believe